# Convert 3D Raycast to Raycast2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite, raycasting

I have this code below which could control a touched player among 3 players. I was able to implement it by like sort of "cheating" by way of adding a 3D cube behind a 2D sprite since my game should be in 2D and I am having hard time implementing it in 2D. I'm really confused on how to do it in 2D because I'm really confuse on the parameters.

Although I already implemented it by the way mentioned above, I still want to implement it in pure 2D. And  because I have this problem when the selected player moves, the sprite moves faster.

```
public GameObject target = null;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
   if(Input.touchCount > 0 || Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
   {
       Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
       Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin,ray.direction * 20,Color.red);
       RaycastHit hit;
       if(Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit,Mathf.Infinity))
       {
            Debug.Log(hit.transform.gameObject.name);
            if(this.target != null){
                SelectMove sm = this.target.GetComponent<SelectMove>();
                if(sm != null){ sm.enabled = false; }
            }
            target = hit.transform.gameObject; 
            //Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
            selectedPlayer();
        }
    }
}

void selectedPlayer(){
    SelectMove sm = this.target.GetComponent<SelectMove>();
    if(sm == null){
        target.AddComponent<SelectMove>();
    }
    sm.enabled = true;  
}
```

Comment: You are looking to translate the 3D touch code to 2D?

Comment: I mean, how could I translate it?

Comment: I found this code in the unity docu: `public static RaycastHit2D Raycast(Vector2 origin, Vector2 direction, float distance = Mathf.Infinity, int layerMask = DefaultRaycastLayers, float minDepth = -Mathf.Infinity, float maxDepth = Mathf.Infinity);`  and in the example code, it only has 2parameters: `RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector2.up);`. I'm not really good in understanding documentations.

Comment: I had the answer but I wasn't really sure if that is what you are asking. check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `RaycastHit2D` to do this instead of `RaycastHit` then change `Physics.Raycast` to `Physics2D.Raycast`. The parameters are different the code below should do it.You may also have to change `&&` to `||` depending on your game logic.

Select the **Sprite** then add **Box Colider 2D** from the Editor. You can also use **Circle Collider 2D** for the Sprite if your Sprite is round. If you don't add any 2D collider to the Sprite, ray won't detect the object when clicked on.

**FOR MOBILE DEVICES**

```
if ((Input.touchCount > 0) && (Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began))
  {
            Vector2 cubeRay = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
            RaycastHit2D cubeHit = Physics2D.Raycast(cubeRay, Vector2.zero);
            if (cubeHit)
            {
                //We hit something
                Debug.Log(cubeHit.transform.gameObject.name);
                if (this.target != null)
                {
                    SelectMove sm = this.target.GetComponent<SelectMove>();
                    if (sm != null) { sm.enabled = false; }
                }
                target = cubeHit.transform.gameObject;
                //Destroy(cubeHit.transform.gameObject);
                selectedPlayer();
            }
  }
```

**FOR DESKTOPS / EDITOR**

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            Vector2 cubeRay = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            RaycastHit2D cubeHit = Physics2D.Raycast(cubeRay, Vector2.zero);
            if (cubeHit)
            {
                //We hit something
                Debug.Log(cubeHit.transform.gameObject.name);
                if (this.target != null)
                {
                    SelectMove sm = this.target.GetComponent<SelectMove>();
                    if (sm != null) { sm.enabled = false; }
                }
                target = cubeHit.transform.gameObject;
                //Destroy(cubeHit.transform.gameObject);
                selectedPlayer();
            }
        }
```

Comment: I have this another sprite where it has a script attached, it moves left and right automatically. Then if I click anywhere, it returns its name to the console. I disabled it so that it leaves me just the sprite I added (with the script). I clicked it but it didn't work. I hit it and it doesn't move.

Comment: You said "Convert 3D Raycast to Raycast2D". That's what the code posted does. Because you said it returns the name to the console, this means that convert to 2d part is working. you are currently having problems with your game logic code. Also you did not describe what you are trying to archive. All you are saying is that it not working....

Comment: If you had problem converting the 3D code to 2D like described in your question and question comment, the code above is how you do it.

Comment: What I am trying to achieve is to click a sprite among 3 sprites and able to control it. Since raycast don't work on 2D sprites, I added a 3D cube behind it so that raycast will work. So it's a cheating. Now, what I need to do is to remove that cube and hit that sprite and control it. My apology if my post is not that clear to understand.

Comment: I modified my answer. Read it from the beginning again.Raycast WORK on Sprite. You need to add 2D Collider to it.  Remove the cube. You no longer need it. Add box collider to the sprite or else the clicks wont be detected.  When working in the editor, use the desktop code. When deploying to your mobile device, use the first code.

Comment: So, I tried everything I could think of and analyzed each line, I don't know why raycast2D won't work properly in my Unity. I tried putting `Vector2 cubeRay = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
            RaycastHit2D cubeHit = Physics2D.Raycast(cubeRay, Vector2.zero);
            Debug.Log("FIRST TEST");
            if (cubeHit != null) { Debug.Log("HIT");   
            }`, it returns the _First test_ and _hit_ although I touched outside the sprite.

Comment: So this is what I did to test it: Created new project -> Added directional light -> added the sprite -> add box collider on it -> attached the script -> run. Am I missing any step? If this still not works, maybe I should make another post why is this not working?

Comment: Zip the project upload it somewhere and post the link here. I plan to be away for hours so it ASAP.

Comment: Also, if I only put `if (cubeHit)`, it won't pass inside it, therefore it won't display _HIT_ but it works on `if (cubeHit != null) `

Comment: You mean the original project or the new one for testing?

Comment: The code works on my side. I will ask you to upload the project. That's the only way I can help at this moment. You said it is a tutorial so why not post the original one with the code that you tried which didnt work.

Comment: got it. will be back

Comment: What is the scene name?

Comment: The scene name is _Play_

Comment: and the c# file name is SelectPlayer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108277/discussion-between-programmer-and-kmf).

Comment: _Tagger3_ is my test sprite and _SM_ is the C# Script.